# probability of throwing at least four dice until get a 6

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem is saying there is this person who throws dice until he gets a 6. What's the probability that he throws at least four dice. I can not simplify this problem without it having a huge number of additions.

$(\frac{5}{6})^3 (\frac{1}{6})^1$ + $(\frac{5}{6})^4 (\frac{1}{6})^1$ + $(\frac{5}{6})^5 (\frac{1}{6})^1$ ...

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try computing the probability that he throws less than four dice instead.

Comment: or the probability that he does'nt throw 6 in the 3 first

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. Your second sentence is *almost* correct (just don't get $1-p$ and $p-1$ mixed up!)

Comment: @Micah thanks for your guidance, it makes perfect sense now!